# Node not found in alpine docker

Tags: node.js, docker, alpine-linux

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.3

RUN apk update \
  && apk add curl tar git gzip

RUN curl --retry 3 --retry-delay 20 --show-error --location --remote-name --silent "https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.2.0/node-v6.2.0-linux-x64.tar.gz" \
  && tar -xzf "node-v6.2.0-linux-x64.tar.gz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 --same-owner \
  && rm -rf "node-v6.2.0-linux-x64.tar.gz" \
  && ls -la /usr/local/bin && env \
  && /usr/local/bin/node -v \
  && npm cache clear
```

Building the image gives me:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 13.51 MB
Step 1 : FROM alpine:3.3
 ---> 3e467a6273a3
Step 2 : RUN apk update     && apk add curl tar git gzip # bzip2 build-essential libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev libfontconfig1 libfontconfig1-dev python python-dev python-pip python-virtualenv libkrb5-devENV NODE_VERSION=6.2.0
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 65f46657024a
Step 3 : RUN curl --retry 3 --retry-delay 20 --show-error --location --remote-name --silent "https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.2.0/node-v6.2.0-linux-x64.tar.gz"     && tar -xzf "node-v6.2.0-linux-x64.tar.gz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 --same-owner     && rm -rf "node-v6.2.0-linux-x64.tar.gz"     && ls -la /usr/local/bin && env     && /usr/local/bin/node -v     && npm cache clear
 ---> Running in 32967b91e2dd
total 26828
drwxrwxr-x    2 500      500           4096 May 17 19:40 .
drwxr-xr-x   10 root     root          4096 May 24 14:28 ..
-rwxrwxr-x    1 500      500       27459658 May 17 19:40 node
lrwxrwxrwx    1 500      500             38 May 17 19:40 npm ->     ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
HOSTNAME=27c9668b3d5e
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
/bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/node: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c curl --retry 3 --retry-delay 20 --show-error --location --remote-name --silent "https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.2.0/node-v6.2.0-linux-x64.tar.gz"     && tar -xzf "node-v6.2.0-linux-x64.tar.gz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 --same-owner     && rm -rf "node-v6.2.0-linux-x64.tar.gz"     && ls -la /usr/local/bin && env     && /usr/local/bin/node -v     && npm cache clear' returned a non-zero code: 127
Build image failed
```

How is it possible for node to not be found? 
It's installed in the correct directory, it's in the path, and has execution permission...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an [official and up to date node package for alpine](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/nodejs), you don't need to install it manually, just add this line in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN apk add nodejs=6.2.0-r0
```

Or you could use an [existing nodejs alpine image](https://hub.docker.com/r/mhart/alpine-node/):

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:6.2.0
```

On a side note, the whole point of using an alpine based image is to get rid of the clutter, installing git, tar et al. is a waste of space IMHO.

Comment: Well, I guess you are right. I wanted flexibility with building my custom node image, but I guess this works too.

Comment: @Petru you can also use [mhart/alpine-node's Dockerfile](https://github.com/mhart/alpine-node/blob/0493edba910ec6e6f0598acb27e7578631cdfc4a/Dockerfile), it gives you a functioning script and you can customize it like you want.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. It seems overly complicated, that's why I tried to make my own simplified version. This was working with a debian base, but alpine gives this strange error :(

Comment: I installed nodejs with `RUN apk add nodejs=6.2.0-r0` but when I try to run a script with `node index.js` or `nodejs index.js` or `/usr/bin/node index.js` fails.

Comment: @diugalde Alpine's repo doesn't have the 6.2.0 version anymore : https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=nodejs You'll have to use an existing version of nodejs or use the ready to use and actively maintained **mhart/alpine-node** Docker image.